# how to send room name from one app to other in jitsi meet

Tags: android, jitsi

Hi In my application I am jitsi libray to make video call option.How to set dynamic room and send it as request .if other person accepts the request only both should be connected .

Can any one help me how to acheieve

```
 join=rootView.findViewById(R.id.join);
        try {
            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                   .setServerURL(new URL("https://google.com/doc123"))
                     .setRoom("test123")
                    .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                    .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onButtonClick(v);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly do you wish to do?
If you just want to generate a random string as a room name, you can use UUID.randomUUID().toString();, in case you wish to get completely random characters.

Comment: after generating random id how to send random id to another user as a request

Comment: Do you wish to send it as email, or something like application deep link ?

Comment: yes sure......give me your mail id

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, do you wish to send the room name to the other user as an email, or do you wish to send a link to them, which when opened can start the video call, like google meet?

Comment: Not through email like google meet yes

Comment: can you have option to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Deep linking for the purpose.

This is the google search for Deep link.

> A deep link is an intent filter system that allows users to directly enter a specific activity in an Android app

One of the most famous services for deep links is Firebase. You can use Firebase dynamic links to create deep links for your app and serve the purpose you wish to.